# How does this 1inch swap result in the user receiving almost double the value of the swapped tokens?

Tags: erc-20, etherscan

When I look at the following transaction on etherscan, it appears this user swapped $188.89 worth of a token called MOTG for $303.75 worth of USDT. Can someone explain how that happened? I don't understand the multiple ERC20 transfers that take place as a result of this transaction, maybe that has something to do with it?

Transaction hash:

0xc1c9c264bc4fdbd78ade90d30b81c1c46d39bc9c53c937c016ff8468303a9952

Answer (score 0):

1inch can be used as a swap aggregator. In this case itt was instructed to swap the chain MOTG-WETH-USDT. The big difference was in the first swap MOTG-WETH.

It is not clear what's the problem. It could that Etherscan isn't showing the correct price, the pool didn't have the correct price, etc.